# Woocommerce change product variation via JS

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

Here's a working example of where we are: http://fpusa.drunk.kiwi/product/ship-your-idea-2/

I am trying to create 'swatches' for a user to click, which would than change the value of the hidden select box woocommerce uses to grab the variation data.

Is there a specific way to tell woocommerce to read the value of the select box?

**Everything works as expected but the javascript event which changes the variation id and gets everything ready to add to cart never happens.**

**Note:** I hide the wc_dropdown with d-none because I thought it would minimize a custom solution.

**Variable.php** - Calls fpusa_product_attribute_button();

```
<?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) : ?>

  <tr class="">
    <td class="label"><label for="<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ); // WPCS: XSS ok. ?></label></td>
        <td class="value">
            <?php
              fpusa_product_attribute_button( $options, $attribute_name, $product );

              wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options( array(
                'options'   => $options,
                'attribute' => $attribute_name,
                'product'   => $product,
                'class'         => 'd-none',
              ));

            echo end( $attribute_keys ) === $attribute_name ? wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reset_variations_link', '<a class="reset_variations" href="#">' . esc_html__( 'Clear', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' ) ) : '';

            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**fpusa_product_attribute_button()**

```
function fpusa_product_attribute_button( $options, $attribute_name, $product ){
    if( ! empty( $options ) ) : ?>
        <div id="var_btn" class="d-flex">
            <?php foreach( $options as $option ): ?>
                <button type="button" class="d-flex btn justify-content-center align-items-center border mx-1" data-key="<?php echo $attribute_name ?>" data-value="<? echo $option ?>">
                    <?php echo $option; ?>
                </button>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div> <?php
    endif;
}
```

**Functions.js**

```js
$('#var_btn button').click(function(){
   let attribute = $(this).attr('data-key');
   let option = $(this).attr('data-value');
   console.log( attribute, option );
   $('#' + attribute).val( option );
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All I had to do is simply trigger the change event on the `<select>` was passing the selected option to.

```
$('#var_btn button').click(function(){
    let attribute = $(this).attr('data-key');
    let option = $(this).attr('data-value');
    console.log( attribute, option );
    $('#' + attribute).val( option ).change();
  });
```